# Autocomplete dropdown multiple select swiftui

Tags: drop-down-menu, swiftui

Im trying to make a predicting textfield ( where you write inside an input and a list of suggestions appear below, like a dropdown) but you can select one or many predicted values, the textfield must show the selected values separated by commas, just like selecting contacts when you are sending an email.

I need to hide the list every time a value is selected and add that value to the textfield with the other values.

I can't make the textfield keep the values ​​you select from the autocomplete, it needs to be able to add another value by autocompleting without removing the first one (autocomplete textfield)

I have already tried to hide the list basing in a boolean called showContactList, but when a value is selected the dropdown from the autocomplete is shown again, and if you select a second value it will replaces the first value

The autocomplete is from simonloewe [TextFieldInputPrediction](https://github.com/simonloewe/TextFieldInputPrediction/blob/master/Example/Example_TextFieldPrediction.swift)

```
 PredictingTextField(predictableValues: self.$predictableValues, predictedValues: self.$predictedValue, textFieldInput: self.$textFieldInput, textFieldTitle: "Para:", showContactList: self.$showContactList )
                   // if(self.predictedValue.count > 0){
                    if(self.showContactList){
                        ZStack{
                            List() {
                                ForEach(self.predictedValue, id: \.self){ value in
                                    Text("\(value.option)" as String)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            print(value)
                                            self.showContactList.toggle()
                                            self.textFieldInput = value.option
                                            self.destinatarios.append(value.value)
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                            .zIndex(10)
                            
                        }
                    }
```

and this is the changes i made to the autocomplete to be able to hide or show the list.

```
struct PredictingTextField: View {

/// All possible predictable values. Can be only one.
@Binding var predictableValues: Array<Contactos>?

/// This returns the values that are being predicted based on the predictable values
@Binding var predictedValues:  Array<Contactos>

/// Current input of the user in the TextField. This is Binded as perhaps there is the urge to alter this during live time. E.g. when a predicted value was selected and the input should be cleared
@Binding var textFieldInput: String

@Binding var showContactList: Bool

/// The time interval between predictions based on current input. Default is 0.1 second. I would not recommend setting this to low as it can be CPU heavy.
@State var predictionInterval: Double?

/// Placeholder in empty TextField
@State var textFieldTitle: String?

@State private var isBeingEdited: Bool = false



init(predictableValues: Binding<Array<Contactos>?>, predictedValues: Binding<[Contactos]>, textFieldInput: Binding<String>, textFieldTitle: String? = "", predictionInterval: Double? = 0.1, showContactList: Binding<Bool>){
    
    self._predictableValues = predictableValues
    self._predictedValues = predictedValues
    self._textFieldInput = textFieldInput
    self._showContactList = showContactList
    self.textFieldTitle = textFieldTitle
    self.predictionInterval = predictionInterval
}

var body: some View {
    TextField("Para:", text: self.$textFieldInput, onEditingChanged: { editing in self.realTimePrediction(status: editing)}, onCommit: { self.makePrediction()})
}

/// Schedules prediction based on interval and only a if input is being made
private func realTimePrediction(status: Bool) {
    self.isBeingEdited = status
    if status == true {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.predictionInterval ?? 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.makePrediction()
            
            if self.isBeingEdited == false {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Capitalizes the first letter of a String
private func capitalizeFirstLetter(smallString: String) -> String {
    return smallString.prefix(1).capitalized + smallString.dropFirst()
}

/// Makes prediciton based on current input
private func makePrediction() {
    self.predictedValues = []
    if !self.textFieldInput.isEmpty{
        for value in self.predictableValues! {
            if self.textFieldInput.split(separator: " ").count > 1 {
                self.makeMultiPrediction(value: value)
                self.showContactList = true
            }else {
                if value.option.contains(self.textFieldInput) || value.option.contains(self.capitalizeFirstLetter(smallString: self.textFieldInput)){
                    
                    
                    
                    if !self.predictedValues.contains(value) {
                        self.predictedValues.append(value)
                        self.showContactList = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Makes predictions if the input String is splittable
private func makeMultiPrediction(value: Contactos) {
    for subString in self.textFieldInput.split(separator: " ") {
        if value.option.contains(String(subString)) || value.option.contains(self.capitalizeFirstLetter(smallString: String(subString))){
            if !self.predictedValues.contains(value) {
                self.predictedValues.append(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, let alone defined your problem. While you state what you are trying to accomplish, you haven't shown how you have failed to accomplish this. Further, with the limited amount of code, no one can even guess what your actual issue is. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks, i've edited the question @Yrb

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have bound to a single value variable, and the selection simply updates, or, more clearly said, replaces the value. There would be two ways to handle it, one with an array that you could map into a single text value to show in the TextField (more complicated), or you could simply add the next selected text to the variable.

Try changing your `.tapGesture` to:

```
.onTapGesture {
    print(value)
    self.showContactList.toggle()
    self.textFieldInput = self.textFieldInput + ", " + value.option
    self.destinatarios.append(value.value)
}
```

This will give you comma separated text that you can deal with as needed. Please note that you will have to deal with removing the extra ", " yourself.